# Concatenate value from resource file with KO observable

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have to string concatenate value from resource file with KO observable string. 
Here is what I tried

[image]

But I'm getting error message

Message: Office is not defined
    at text (eval at parseBindingsString (knockout-3.4.0.js:68), :3:82)
    at update (knockout-3.4.0.js:98)
    at function.a.B.i (knockout-3.4.0.js:72)
    at Function.Pc (knockout-3.4.0.js:51)
    at Function.Qc (knockout-3.4.0.js:51)
    at Function.aa (knockout-3.4.0.js:50)
    at Object.a.m.a.B (knockout-3.4.0.js:49)
    at knockout-3.4.0.js:72
    at Object.q (knockout-3.4.0.js:11)
    at m (knockout-3.4.0.js:71)

"Office is not defined" here Office is value I get from resource file for @Resources.Office.

Comment: You could create a computed observable:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html.  All the code inside the 'text' binding goes into the 'fullName' in the link.

Comment: Yeah that is one good option. But is there any way to do this without computed observable?

Answer (score 1):

can you pass your resource file into the viewmodel?  then you should have access to it. run snippet below.

```js
function model(Resources) {
  var self = this;
  this.Resources = ko.observable(Resources);
  this.foo = ko.observable({
    WorkPhone: true,
    CellPhone: false
  });
}

var Resources = {
  'Office': '222-2222',
  'OfficeMobile': '333-3333',
  'Home': '444-4444'
}
var mymodel = new model(Resources);

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(mymodel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="with: foo">
  <span data-bind="text: $data.WorkPhone ? 
                        'Office: ' + $parent.Resources().Office + 
                        ' ,Office Mobile: ' + $parent.Resources().OfficeMobile
                        : 'Home: ' + $parent.Resources().Home"></span>
</div>
```

although I agree with Jose that a computed or pure computed is probably a better way to go.